# Simple.Data ORM. The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: c#, orm, simple.data

I'm using Simple.Data ORM. I'm trying to make a query from two joined tables. This query works fine:

```
dynamic alias;
var candidatesRec = db.dbo.Candidates
            .FindAll(db.dbo.Candidates.CommonOfferId == commonOfferId 
                        && db.dbo.CandidateProfiles.CandidateId == null)
            .LeftJoin(db.dbo.CandidateProfiles, out alias)
            .On(db.dbo.Candidates.Id == alias.CandidateId)
            .Select(
                db.dbo.Candidates.Id,
                db.dbo.Candidates.Email
            )
            .OrderByDescending(db.dbo.Candidates.ApplicationDate)
```

But when this line is added:

```
.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
```

I'm getting this exception:

> The multi-part identifier \"dbo.CandidateProfiles.CandidateId\" could
>   not be bound.

I was trying explicitly pass 0, 1 and few other numbers to Skip but I always get the same exception.

My test query should return 4 elements and I'm skipping 0 elements (it can be more in normal use).

Additional info: `CandidateProfiles` has foreign key from `Candidates` and it's `CandidateId` can be null.

Edit: We've done a workaround for this problem, but I'm really curious why this one won't work. Simple.Data looked fun at first, but now I'm not sure if I will use it in future

Comment: Could you include a script for your table creation so I can try to replicate it locally? From a first glance, it seems like it's a bug within the library - but I'd need to take a closer look at the SQL it's generating (and how it is)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an explanation of the SQL error from http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-4104.aspx:

> Another way of getting the error is when an alias has been assigned to
>   a table referenced in the FROM clause of a statement and the table is
>   used as a prefix of a column instead of using the alias.

While this isn't quite what's happening in your case, it's very close.  The problem I see with your code sample is in the **FindAll** call:

```
        .FindAll(db.dbo.Candidates.CommonOfferId == commonOfferId 
                    && db.dbo.CandidateProfiles.CandidateId == null)
        .LeftJoin(db.dbo.CandidateProfiles, out alias)
```

Since the **FindAll** is using the fully qualified name "db.dbo.CandidateProfiles" and every other reference is using the alias defined in the subsequent **LeftJoin**, the occurrence in the generated **where** clause doesn't use the alias, and you end up with a mix and match of alias and explicit table references, that SQL doesn't like.

I think the reason that it only occurred in your case after the "Skip" was added, is that very different SQL ended up being generated (my guess is that only after the Skip was added was an alias actually used).

I don't understand the purpose of the **CandidateProfiles.CandidateId == null** condition (because combined with the condition in the **On** call I don't see how this would ever return any results), but I would suggest adding restrictions to the joined table in the **On** call so that it ends up in the **on** clause instead of the **where** clause (and then using the alias instead of the fully qualified name)

```
.LeftJoin(db.dbo.CandidateProfiles, out alias)  
.On(db.dbo.Candidates.Id == alias.CandidateId && alias.CandidateId == null)
```